# C# Winforms | I can't get values from Form in new class

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, tcplistener, tcpserver

I am trying to make a Async TCP Server/Client with C# in Winforms. I have done it from the console and everything was fine.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartListener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AsyncSocketListener.StartListener();
        }

        public class ObjectState { 
            public Socket socket = null;
            public const int bufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public class AsyncSocketListener { 
            public static ManualResetEvent completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            
            public static void StartListener()
            {
                Form1 objects = new Form1();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                int port = int.Parse(objects.ServerPort.Text);
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(objects.ServerIP.Text);
                IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
                Socket listener = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                try
                {
                    listener.Bind(ep);
                    listener.Listen(999999999);

                    while (true) { 
                        completed.Reset();
                        MessageBox.Show("Listener started: Waiting for incoming connections", "Listener started", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), listener);
                    }
                } 

                catch (Exception a) {
                    MessageBox.Show(a.Message, "Error - Listener failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

            private static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar) { 
                completed.Set();
                Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

                ObjectState state = new ObjectState();
                state.socket = handler;
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ObjectState.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), state);
            }

            private static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                string content = String.Empty;
                ObjectState state = (ObjectState) ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.socket;
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                    content = state.sb.ToString();
                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Read: {content.Length} bytes from socket Data: {content}", "Socket data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        Send(handler, content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ObjectState.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), state);
                    }
                }
            }

            private static void Send(Socket handler, String content)
            {
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
                handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
            }

            private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try { 
                    Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
                    int byteSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                    MessageBox.Show($"Sent: {byteSent} to client", "Socket data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Socket Callback Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When doing it with GUI, I have problems with the server. In my `AsyncSocketListener` class the `StartListener` function cannot catch the values passed in the GUI TextBoxes.

```
Form1 objects = new Form1();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

int port = int.Parse(objects.ServerPort.Text);
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(objects.ServerIP.Text);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
```

Any idea what is going on here please? Why can't I get the values from the class?

I'm new to C#, sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `Form1()`. That's not the same instance of `Form1()` that (I assume) is being shown. So you've got two different objects, each with independent state.

Comment: (As an aside, I'd encourage you not to use nested classes like this - if all classes are independent top-level classes, it's easier to find them and reason about them.)

Answer (score 0):

So if you look in your listener code at this line

```
Form1 objects = new Form1();
```

You are creating a brand new instance of the Form, and then trying to use the values from here.

You instead need to pass the reference to the original Form.  So try this;

```
public class AsyncSocketListener 
{ 
        public static ManualResetEvent completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        //Amend this to accept a reference to the Form1 object                
        public static void StartListener(Form1 objects)
        {
            //Rest of code as before
```

Then pass the reference like this;

```
 private void StartListener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        AsyncSocketListener.StartListener(this);
 }
```

There are maybe a few other things you can do to improve the code (see comments) including renaming "`objects`" to something more meaningful, such as "`form`".

In fact, it would be even better to totally decouple your `Form1` from your Listener class, and just pass the values into the listener such as this;

```
 public static void StartListener(IPAddress ip, int port)
 {         
     byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
     //Rest of code as before
```

Pass the reference like this;

```
private void StartListener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AsyncSocketListener.StartListener(IPAddress.Parse(this.ServerIP.Text), int.Parse(this.ServerPort.Text));
}
```